# Is there any module / component for historic visit in joomla?

Tags: joomla, module, components

I asked this question because I have the following situation. A website where I need to have the control that the items that the user is accessing, and create a kind of history with him. I can solve this problem easily by doing a bit of manual work, but since I started studying joomla someone told me that it is not good to create loose tables in the database and make changes (do not know if it's true). So I wonder if anyone knows anything or any idea where I can do this kind of control. Thank you.

Comment: It's definitely better to make a new extension than to mess with core code.  Can you explain what kind of history you mean? I'm sure I've seen extensions that do things like track if a user has actually watch ed a vide.

Comment: I want to register article views per user. For example, user 'foo' viewed the article 'bar'. As I mentioned above, I can fix everything manually, pure mysql and php, but I do not believe to be correct. So try if anyone knows any extension of that type.

Comment: I'd use a plugin to manage it probably. You can manage the data from the plugin so you at least know about what pages have loaded for a given user.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this: [Joomla Scout](http://dioscouri.com/joomla-extensions/scout-activity-logger)
Also you should consider [FlexiContent](http://www.flexicontent.org/), it has versioning included and works with com_content, you with love this product.